How to assign Default Access role in Terraform to an entra enterprise application
I want to assign my AAD group to the enterprise application. The role assigned should be Default Access as in here 
One way is to create a custom Default Access role and then assign it with azuread_app_role_assignment. However, I'm wondering how to assign this role without creating a custom one since I can do it through the Azure portal.
Currently, my app roles are empty, which is why I can't query the app roles and get the Default Access id 
When I put an empty string for role_id I get 

The solution is the following:
In the terraform documentation, https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/app_role_assignment I found out this 
My terraform code is following: 
I've tried it and it is working as expected.
